# Не находит вхождение для оператора сравнения LIKE

Tags: регулярные-выражения, oracle12c

Почему это выражение не находит вхождение маски для LIKE?

```
select 1 from dual where 'ING_H' like '%[_]H'
```

H - английская ))

Comment: `select 1 from dual where 'ING_H' like '%_H'`

Comment: Неверно. Смотрите комментарии под ответом @Wiktor Stribiżew ниже

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `like` работает с подстановочными знаками (англ. *wildcard*), не с регулярными выражениями.

У вас `'%[_]H'` смесь регулярного выражения с подстановочными знаками, поэтому нужно убрать шаблон регулярки, заменить *символьный класс регулярных выражений* `[_]` на `\_`:

```
select 1 from dual where 'ING_H' like '%\_H' escape '\'
```

Так как `_` в `like` — подстановочный знак, находящий 1 любой символ, его нужно экранировать. Для этого его нужно экранировать, задав соответствующий символ с помощью оператора `escape`.

`[...]` ничего не экранирует в регулярных выражениях, это *символьный класс*, в котором можно задать символы или диапазоны символов, и он найдёт только один из этих символов. В `like` нет экранирующего символа по умолчанию, [его надо задать вручную](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm):

> Если `esc_char` не указан, экранирующего символа по умолчанию нет.

См. [демо онлайн](https://rextester.com/ICX53119).

В данном случае нет нужды в регулярном выражении, лучше использовать `like`, но в образовательных целях приведу пример с регуляркой:

```
where regexp_like('ING_H', '.*_H$')
where regexp_like('ING_H', '_H$')
```

Тут `.*` эквивалентен `%`, этот шаблон находит 0 и более любых символов, а `$` означает конец строки (`regexp_like` не требует совпадения целой строки).

Comment: Неверно. _ - это подстановочный символ, заменяющий вхождение любого одного символа. Чтобы указать, что это обозначение символа, а не маска, я его экранирую [*]. А в ваш пример работает потому что соответствует выражению "Любой символ перед H". Вот так он работает тоже: select 1 from dual where 'AH' like '_H'

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст А вот так  - ``select 1 from dual where 'ING.H' like '%\_H' escape '\'``   - работает как надо.

Comment: C escape работает, конечно. Но у меня вопрос именно в том почему стандартное экранирование спецсимволов не работает в моем примере. Меня интересует не решение, а причина )))

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст Я добавил доп. информацию в ответ.

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст Если что-то ещё неясно, дайте знать - добавлю.